# Oblique Table View in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to make a oblique scrolling table or collection view.
I'm using objective-c.
I thought I could rotate the table 45 degrees but the problem is that it rotates the cells too.
I can even do it with a collection view if it's easier to achieve.
[image: What I want to achieve basically.]
The white cells are table view/collection view cells.

Comment: What about using a normal table view but width a big width (depending on amount of your cells)? Every cell would have the content shifted depending on your needs. For example the first cell's content would be at the most right of frame of the cell. The next one would be a bit shifted to the left and so on.

Comment: Just apply a negative transform of same value on the cells. For example, if you're applying a rotation transform of +45 degrees on table view, apple a rotation transform of -45 degrees on cells. Test the touch behaviour though.